# TV show / Film where a space ship breaks apart in a supernatural way near the end

Tags: story-identification, tv, soft-sci-fi

I am having a super difficult time remembering this. I believe it was a TV show but it might have been a film (about 95% sure it was a TV show). I believe the premise was that some planet had an area that had a lot of funky, strange things going on, ships being lost inside it, etc. I think near the end of a season, or at the end of a season, a ship makes it with someone inside it, but once they are approaching the source of all the issues, the ship itself kind of disintegrates, as if it was completely pulled apart from all its components, and the person/people inside it are left floating in this atmosphere. It's shown in a way that is not scientifically explainable, so it's more just a great sequence that I'd like to see again. It wasn't too old, definitely within the last 10 years, probably within the last 5 years.

Comment: This question would be improved if you went through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens in [Season 2, Episode 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Expanse_episodes) of *The Expanse*. Titled "The Monster and the Rocket", the episode aired on April 12, 2017.

In the previous season,

> the colonized asteriod Eros, heavily infected with the protomolecule, is crashed into Venus to neutralize the threat it poses.

Earth sends a survey ship to investigate reports of strange phenomena at the crash site.  One of the story arcs of Season 2 follows this ship's voyage. But in the episode in question,

> As the science team aboard the Arboghast begins a descent to the surface of Venus for a closer look at the protomolecule structure, the ship is completely stopped and then disassembled in an increasing spherical pattern, the fate of its crew unknown.

(the latter quoted from Wikipedia.).

This appears supernatural, but

> it's an action of the protomolecule, which has an unexplained (almost godlike) control over space, matter, and/ or mind.

Comment: This is exactly it, thank you so much!

Comment: @drucom Please confirm the answer as the right one, thank you.